# Binary matrix with (max 2) contiguous blocks of 1's as rows, calculate trace of its square

Tags: algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra

Let `A` be an `nxn` binary matrix whose rows are of the form `0^k 1^l 0^m` or `1^k 0^l 1^m`. Also, `A` has zeros along the diagonal. The dimension n can be up to `10^5`. The matrix will be given by giving the indices where the blocks of `1`'s start and end.

In other words, the rows are a run of `1`'s surrounded by `0`'s or a run of `0`'s surrounded by `1`'s. A row can be all zeros, but not all ones (zero on the diagonal).

An example `A`:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**How to calculate trace of `A^2` efficiently** (under `O(n^2)` time)?

This is equivalent to finding the `(n-2)`'nd coefficient of the characteristic polynomial of A, denote it `g_2(A)`, since

```
tr(A^2) = (tr A)^2 - 2g_2(A) = -2g_2(A)
```

---

*A little bit where this problem comes from:*

We are given a permutation p of the numbers [1..n] and are interested in the quantity

```
r(p) = #{k | p^{-1}[k+1] < p^{-1}[k]}
```

Here `p^{-1}[k]` means the index of `k` in `p`. We want to count all the swaps of two elements that decrease r by 2. This can be done by considering for each index `k` where `p[k]` is profitable to move. It depends on the positions of `p[k]-1` and `p[k]+1` (only on other one in edge cases) and this is where the form for the rows comes from. But also the moving of the other element should be profitable, hence the question becomes how many element in the matrix `A` have both `A[i][j]` and `A[j][i]` equal to `1` and we are lead to count the trace of `A^2`. Further, in the original question we want to subtract from this the pairs that are adjacent numbers `(|p[i]-p[j]|==1)`, since that won't decrease `r` by 2 but only by 1. But this can be done in linear time and for simplicity isn't considered for this question. Although, it could be that the original question imposes some further restrictions on the matrix `A` that could help in the calculation(?)

Comment: This seems like it should be possible but not easy. The entries of A^2 are each scalar products of a row and a column of A; the rows of A follow a simple structure but the columns do not. We need a way to efficiently count how many rows in a given range have a 1 in a given column, so in that sense this is more a data structures problem than an algorithm problem.

Comment: Another idea is to decompose `A = (L + M + R)` where `L` is the matrix with just the 1s at the starts of rows, `M` has just the 1s in the middles of rows, and `R` has just the 1s at the ends of rows. The expansion of `A^2 = (L + M + R)(L + M + R)` requires nine multiplications instead of one, but each of the multiplications is in a simpler form so it might be easier to find a sub-quadratic-time algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in O(n log n) time with a [sweep-line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) using a [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree).

The algorithm computes the entries of the diagonal of the product in order. It maintains a Fenwick tree that holds the current column. The Fenwick tree can update an entry in time O(log n) and report a subarray sum in time O(log n). For each partial row of ones in positions {i} × {j…j'-1}, we create two events, (j, i, +1) and (j', i, -1). Sort and group the events by their first entry (the column, a.k.a. time). An event (j, i, Δ) means at time j, increment entry i by Δ. To compute diagonal element index k, first apply all of the events with time k, then report all of the intervals of ones in the corresponding row, and sum them.

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant! Unfortunately I don't have enough repu to give +1. Solving time for the original problem went from 19 minutes to 6 seconds :D